# Golang and apache AB

Tags: java, go

I have a system with HTTP POST requests and it runs with Spring 5 (standalone tomcat). In short it looks like this:

client (Apache AB) ----> micro service (java or golang) --> RabbitMQ --> Core(spring + tomcat).

The thing is, when I use my Java (Spring) service, it is ok. AB shows this output:

```
ab -n 1000 -k -s 2 -c 10 -s 60 -p test2.sh -A 113:113 -T 'application/json' https://127.0.0.1:8449/SecureChat/chat/v1/rest-message/send 
This is ApacheBench, Version 2.3 <$Revision: 1807734 $> 
Copyright 1996 Adam Twiss, Zeus Technology Ltd, http://www.zeustech.net/
Licensed to The Apache Software Foundation, http://www.apache.org/

Benchmarking 127.0.0.1 (be patient)
Completed 100 requests
...
Completed 1000 requests
Finished 1000 requests


Server Software:        
Server Hostname:        127.0.0.1
Server Port:            8449
SSL/TLS Protocol:       TLSv1.2,ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384,2048,256

Document Path:          /rest-message/send
Document Length:        39 bytes

Concurrency Level:      10
Time taken for tests:   434.853 seconds
Complete requests:      1000
Failed requests:        0
Keep-Alive requests:    0
Total transferred:      498000 bytes
Total body sent:        393000
HTML transferred:       39000 bytes
Requests per second:    2.30 [#/sec] (mean)
Time per request:       4348.528 [ms] (mean)
Time per request:       434.853 [ms] (mean, across all concurrent 
requests)
Transfer rate:          1.12 [Kbytes/sec] received
                    0.88 kb/s sent
                    2.00 kb/s total

Connection Times (ms)
              min  mean[+/-sd] median   max
Connect:        4   14   7.6     17      53
Processing:  1110 4317 437.2   4285    8383
Waiting:     1107 4314 437.2   4282    8377
Total:       1126 4332 436.8   4300    8403
```

That is through TLS.

But when I try to use my Golang service I get timeout:

```
Benchmarking 127.0.0.1 (be patient)...apr_pollset_poll: The timeout specified has expired (70007)
Total of 92 requests completed
```

And this output:

```
ab -n 100 -k -s 2 -c 10 -s 60 -p test2.sh -T 'application/json' http://127.0.0.1:8089/
This is ApacheBench, Version 2.3 <$Revision: 1807734 $>
Copyright 1996 Adam Twiss, Zeus Technology Ltd, http://www.zeustech.net/
Licensed to The Apache Software Foundation, http://www.apache.org/

Benchmarking 127.0.0.1 (be patient)...^C

Server Software:        
Server Hostname:        127.0.0.1
Server Port:            8089

Document Path:          /
Document Length:        39 bytes

Concurrency Level:      10
Time taken for tests:   145.734 seconds
Complete requests:      92
Failed requests:        1
   (Connect: 0, Receive: 0, Length: 1, Exceptions: 0)
Keep-Alive requests:    91
Total transferred:      16380 bytes
Total body sent:        32200
HTML transferred:       3549 bytes
Requests per second:    0.63 [#/sec] (mean)
Time per request:       15840.663 [ms] (mean)
Time per request:       1584.066 [ms] (mean, across all concurrent requests)
Transfer rate:          0.11 [Kbytes/sec] received
                        0.22 kb/s sent
                        0.33 kb/s total

Connection Times (ms)
              min  mean[+/-sd] median   max
Connect:        0    0   0.0      0       0
Processing:  1229 1494 1955.9   1262   20000
Waiting:     1229 1291 143.8   1262    2212
Total:       1229 1494 1955.9   1262   20000

That is through plane tcp.
```

I guess I have some mistakes in my code. I made it in one file

```
func initAmqp(rabbitUrl string) {
    var err error
    conn, err = amqp.Dial(rabbitUrl)
    failOnError(err, "Failed to connect to RabbitMQ")
}

func main() {
    err := gcfg.ReadFileInto(&cfg, "config.gcfg")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err);
    }

    PrintConfig(cfg)

    if cfg.Section_rabbit.RabbitUrl != "" {
        initAmqp(cfg.Section_rabbit.RabbitUrl);
    }

    mux := http.NewServeMux();
    mux.Handle("/", NewLimitHandler(1000, newTestHandler()))
    server := http.Server {
        Addr:   cfg.Section_basic.Port,
        Handler:    mux,
        ReadTimeout: 20 * time.Second,
        WriteTimeout: 20 * time.Second,
    }

    defer conn.Close();
    log.Println(server.ListenAndServe());
}

func NewLimitHandler(maxConns int, handler http.Handler) http.Handler {
    h := &limitHandler{
        connc:   make(chan struct{}, maxConns),
        handler: handler,
    }
    for i := 0; i < maxConns; i++ {
        h.connc <- struct{}{}
    }
    return h
}

func newTestHandler() http.Handler {
    return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        handler(w, r);
    })
}

func handler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    if b, err := ioutil.ReadAll(r.Body); err == nil {

        fmt.Println("message is ", string(b));
        res := publishMessages(string(b))

        w.Write([]byte(res))
        w.WriteHeader(http.StatusOK)
        counter ++;
    }else {
        w.WriteHeader(http.StatusInternalServerError)
        w.Write([]byte("500 - Something bad happened!"))
    }
}

func publishMessages(payload string) string {
    ch, err := conn.Channel()
    failOnError(err, "Failed to open a channel")

    q, err = ch.QueueDeclare(
        "",    // name
        false, // durable
        false, // delete when unused
        true,  // exclusive
        false, // noWait
        nil,   // arguments
    )

    failOnError(err, "Failed to declare a queue")

    msgs, err := ch.Consume(
        q.Name, // queue
        "",     // consumer
        true,   // auto-ack
        false,  // exclusive
        false,  // no-local
        false,  // no-wait
        nil,    // args
    )
    failOnError(err, "Failed to register a consumer")

    corrId := randomString(32)

    log.Println("corrId ", corrId)

    err = ch.Publish(
        "",                 // exchange
        cfg.Section_rabbit.RabbitQeue,      // routing key
        false,              // mandatory
        false,              // immediate
        amqp.Publishing{
            DeliveryMode: amqp.Transient,
            ContentType:  "application/json",
            CorrelationId: corrId,
            Body:         []byte(payload),
            Timestamp:    time.Now(),
            ReplyTo:       q.Name,
        })

    failOnError(err, "Failed to Publish on RabbitMQ")

    defer ch.Close();

    result :=  "";
    for d := range msgs {
        if corrId == d.CorrelationId {
            failOnError(err, "Failed to convert body to integer")

            log.Println("result = ", string(d.Body))

            return string(d.Body);

         }else {
            log.Println("waiting for result = ")
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Can someone help?

EDIT
here are my variables

```
type limitHandler struct {
    connc   chan struct{}
    handler http.Handler
}

var conn *amqp.Connection
var q amqp.Queue
```

EDIT 2

```
func (h *limitHandler) ServeHTTP(w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
    select {
    case <-h.connc:


        fmt.Println("ServeHTTP");


        h.handler.ServeHTTP(w, req)

        h.connc <- struct{}{}
    default:
        http.Error(w, "503 too busy", http.StatusServiceUnavailable)
    }
}
```

EDIT 3

```
func failOnError(err error, msg string) {
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("%s: %s", msg, err)
        panic(fmt.Sprintf("%s: %s", msg, err))
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is the definition of `limitHandler`? It seems pretty critical to this code and issue.

Comment: Probably not related, but a quick looks at the http portion shows you're writing the response before the header which doesn't make sense, and you have a data race on `counter`.

Comment: @Adrian - I added limitHandler

Comment: Not all of it. If `limitHandler` can be returned as an `http.Handler`, it must implement `ServeHTTP` which isn't shown and is the relevant code.

Comment: @Adrian, I guess now it is full - sorry for late edit.

Comment: Not sure what `failOnError` does, I'm guessing it `panic`s? If so, your sentinel will never be put back on the channel and your rate limiter will slowly drop to a maximum of zero permitted connections. What do you get in the server output? Any errors or anything?

Comment: @Adrian no errors at all. Bu the way - I commented "for d := range msgs ... " and AB worked great. May be I get result from Rabbit MQ in the wrong way?

Comment: I would not be surprised at all if it's something to do with the RabbitMQ interraction. But there's a lot of moving parts in this code, I'm not sure it's possible for this to be answered on SO. One would likely have to recreate your entire setup and run the program to figure out what is going on.